# VBA-excel code for sorting and calculating data from a matrix

Tags: vba, excel, matrix

I've gotten a lot of help from here before but since I couldn't find any help this time so I created this account to ask a question. 
I am not super good with VBA but I'm learning and I think it's fun!

I can download all my bank data in a matrix/table format. It's mainly 3 types of transaction (see image below):

1. Price of buy/sell shares
2. dividends
3. withdrawls/deposits

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wdbgu.jpg  (<-- I need 10 reputation to post this image, so i can only link it here.)

I'll paste this data (which can be of any length and size) into a tab, "Data", in excel and then I would like to create a macro button which will do the following things;

On first tab, "Portfolio", the macro should sort and calculate the data for only the buy and sell of shares and present it into 4 colums:

- Company
- Number of shares
- Average price
- Total value

So if I have bought shares in Company X two times and sold shares one time, I want the macro to calculate the average price of those transactions, sum up the total quantity I own and the total value of those shares.
The macro should do this for all companies and sort it alphabetically.

The result should look kinda like this (but with other values)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjEzJ.jpg  (<-- I need 10 reputation to post this image, so i can only link it here.)

I've tried to create this myself but I am not good with dealing with matrices and looping through them. Plus I need to figure out how big the matrix is - which is the last row and column.

Would appreciate any form of help.

Comment: Look at the Data tab in excel, in particular the sort, filter and subtotal commands. You can probably do this in a few clicks  without any code

Comment: Could probably do this with a pivot table, or some Excel formulas (Sumif, Averageif, etc).  Is there a specific reason you want to use VBA?

Comment: Hi both and thank you for your comments!

The reason why I want to do this in VBA is that I also want to learn how to utilize matrix calculation/manipulation in VBA. I also want to do more with this data (e.g. sort the dividens) but I think I can do that myself if I just learn the first steps.

Comment: Hi @ZeriCo good initiative, but here is not a place to learn how to code. If you want us to help, try code something.